# Regarding My Revoked Passport

Tags: canada, residency

I have a Korean passport and I'm on 3 year PGWP. I'm planning to apply for PR in about 3 months after I gain my 2 year work experience in Canada. The thing is, I have a military duty back in Korea which I'm supposed to start by next month, and if I don't come back to do the service, Korean authority says they will revoke my passport. The question is, can I still apply for PR with my revoked passport even if the expiration on my passport says Nov 2026?
I am curious if they have a system against which they can confirm the validity of my passport. If so, I will have to go back to Korea and serve, and I won't be able to apply for PR, which I try to avoid at all cost. Tbh, I feel so stuck and seem to have no options. Please, advise...

Comment: In this case you really need to talk to a Canadian immigration lawyer AND a Korean lawyer and not to strangers on the Internet. Your actions are going to have VERY serious consequences and it's important that you understand them in great detail. Draft evasion is a serious crime in Korea. and If you evade the draft, you may banned from Korea for ever and/or you may be thrown in jail when you try to enter.

Comment: And committing a crime in Korea may disqualify you from a Canadian Permanent Residences .